# How add <supports-screens> tag android manifest

Tags: android, coronasdk

How to add a tag `<supports-screens>` in the android manifest from file build.settings?

Answer (score 1):

You need to use apktool to open the Corona APK, and then edit the manifest, and then repack again...

[There are a very good tutorial on how to fiddle with apktool and Corona](http://www.ludicroussoftware.com/blog/2012/05/08/remove-unused-libraries-from-corona-apps/)

Unfortunately, this tutorial seemly only apply to build up to 840, the newest build does not work with it...